# Overhead of converting from []byte to string and vice-versa

Tags: string, go

I always seem to be converting strings to []byte to string again over and over. Is there a lot of overhead with this? Is there a better way?

For example, here is a function that accepts a UTF8 string, normalizes it, remove accents, then converts special characters to ASCII equivalent:

```
var transliterations = map[rune]string{'Æ':"AE",'Ð':"D",'Ł':"L",'Ø':"OE",'Þ':"Th",'ß':"ss",'æ':"ae",'ð':"d",'ł':"l",'ø':"oe",'þ':"th",'Œ':"OE",'œ':"oe"}
func RemoveAccents(s string) string {
    b := make([]byte, len(s))
    t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, transform.RemoveFunc(isMn), norm.NFC)
    _, _, e := t.Transform(b, []byte(s), true)
    if e != nil { panic(e) }
    r := string(b)

    var f bytes.Buffer
    for _, c := range r {
        temp := rune(c)
        if val, ok := transliterations[temp]; ok {
            f.WriteString(val)
        } else {
            f.WriteRune(temp)
        }
    }
    return f.String()
}
```

So I'm starting with a string because that's what I get, then I'm converting it to a byte array, then back to a string, then to a byte array again, then back to a string again. Surely this is unnecessary but I can't figure out how to not do this..? And does it really have a lot of overhead or do I not have to worry about slowing things down with excessive conversions?

(Also if anyone has the time I've not yet figured out how `bytes.Buffer` actually works, would it not be better to initialize a buffer of 2x the size of the string, which is the maximum output size of the return value?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go, `string`s are immutable so any change creates a new string. As a general rule, convert from a `string` to a `byte` or `rune` slice once and convert back to a `string` once. To avoid reallocations, for small and transient allocations, over-allocate to provide a safety margin if you don't know the exact number.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
    "unicode/utf8"

    "code.google.com/p/go.text/transform"
    "code.google.com/p/go.text/unicode/norm"
)

var isMn = func(r rune) bool {
    return unicode.Is(unicode.Mn, r) // Mn: nonspacing marks
}

var transliterations = map[rune]string{
    'Æ': "AE", 'Ð': "D", 'Ł': "L", 'Ø': "OE", 'Þ': "Th",
    'ß': "ss", 'æ': "ae", 'ð': "d", 'ł': "l", 'ø': "oe",
    'þ': "th", 'Œ': "OE", 'œ': "oe",
}

func RemoveAccents(b []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    mnBuf := make([]byte, len(b)*125/100)
    t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, transform.RemoveFunc(isMn), norm.NFC)
    n, _, err := t.Transform(mnBuf, b, true)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    mnBuf = mnBuf[:n]
    tlBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, len(mnBuf)*125/100))
    for i, w := 0, 0; i < len(mnBuf); i += w {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRune(mnBuf[i:])
        if s, ok := transliterations[r]; ok {
            tlBuf.WriteString(s)
        } else {
            tlBuf.WriteRune(r)
        }
        w = width
    }
    return tlBuf.Bytes(), nil
}

func main() {
    in := "test stringß"
    fmt.Println(in)
    inBytes := []byte(in)
    outBytes, err := RemoveAccents(inBytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    out := string(outBytes)
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

Output:

```
test stringß
test stringss
```

Comment: Fancy. The `width` seems unnecessary... can I not just make it `r, w := utf8.DecodeRune` and then do away with the `w = width`?

Comment: @Alasdair: No. `i, w := 0, 0` declares `w` for the outer scope. `r, w :=  utf8.DecodeRune` would redeclare `w` for the inner scope. `i += w` uses the `w` in the outer scope, so you will get a "`w declared and not used`" error for the `w` in the inner scope. [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec); [Blocks](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks); [Declarations and scope](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope); [Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

Answer (score 3):

There is no answer to this question. If these conversions are a performance bottleneck in your application you should fix them.  If not: Not.

Did you profile your application under realistic load and `RemoveAccents` is the bottleneck?  No? So why bother?

Really: I assume one could do better (in the sense of less garbage, less iterations and less conversions) e.g. by chaining in some "TransliterationTransformer". But I doubt it would be wirth the hassle.

Comment: Well... I understand what you're saying, but I like to have an idea in my head about the efficiency of my coding style. It's a question of habit to get into rather than profiling and optimizing specific applications.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small overhead with converting a string to a byte *slice* (not an array, that's a [different type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types)). Namely allocating the space for the byte slice.

Strings are its own type and are an interpretation of a sequence of bytes. But not every sequence of bytes is a useful string. Strings are also [immutable](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types). If you look at the [strings package](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/), you will see that strings will be [sliced](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) a lot.

In your example you can omit the second conversion back to string. You can also range over a byte slice.

As with every question about performance: you will probably need to measure. Is the allocation of byte slices really your bottleneck?

You can initialize your `bytes.Buffer` like so:

```
f := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, len(s)*2))
```

where you have a size of 0 and a capacity of 2x the size of your string. If you can estimate the size of your buffer, it is probably good to do that. It will save you a few reallocations of the underlying byte slices.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on initializing the buffer. For the range over the string, I think it does need to be a string because range over string ranges by rune, which is what I need in that case. It could probably be done with a scanner on the byte array, but I haven't learned how to do that yet.

Comment: @Alasdair, you can get runes from a `[]byte` with `bufio.Reader.ReadRune`, or more directly with just `utf8.DecodeRune`.